$X \sim B(n_{X}, p_{X})$ and $Y \sim B(n_{Y}, p_{Y})$ when $p_X\neq p_Y$

Given two independent random variables $X \sim B(n_{X}, p_{X})$ and $Y
\sim B(n_{Y}, p_{Y})$. When $p_{X} \neq p_{Y}$, prove that $X + Y$
does not follow a binomial distribution.

Assume that $X+Y\sim B(n,p)$.
In the solution to this problem my book provides, it proves $n=n_X+n_Y$ that I don't understand: 
If $n<n_X+n_Y$ then $$0=P(X+Y=n_X+n_Y)=P(X=n_X)+(Y=n_Y)=p_X^{n_X}+p_Y^{n_Y} (\text{Absurd})$$
If $n>n_X+n_Y$ then $$p^n=P(X+Y=n)\leq P(X>n_X)+(Y>n_Y)=0(\text{Absurd})$$
Hence, $n=n_X+n_Y$
In the case $n<n_X+n_Y$, I don't get the equality $P(X+Y=n_X+n_Y)=P(X=n_X)+(Y=n_Y)$
In the case $n>n_X+n_Y$, I don't get the equality $P(X+Y=n)\leq P(X>n_X)+(Y>n_Y)$
Could someone explain these for me? Thanks in advance

Are you sure it's not meant to say $P(X+Y=n_X+n_Y)=P(X=n_X)P(Y=n_Y)$?

If $X \le n_X$ and $Y \le n_Y$ then $X + Y \le n_X + n_Y$. So if $X + Y \ge n_X + n_Y$ then at least one of $X > n_X$ or $Y > n_Y$ is true. Meaning if $n > n_X + n_Y$:
$$P(X+Y = n) \le P(X > n_X \cup Y > n_Y) \le P(X > n_X) + P(Y > n_Y)$$
